# Boundary of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

The product of manifolds without boundaries is always a manifold without boundary?

$\textbf{Example:}$ $S^2\times \mathbb R$ has a boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. More generally if $M$ and $N$ are boundary manifolds, then $M\times N$ is a manifold with boundary and $$\partial (M\times N)=\partial M\times N\cup M\times \partial N.$$
So if $\partial M=\partial N=\emptyset$ then $\partial (M\times N)=\emptyset$. Note that here I am talking about topological manifolds.

Comment: If you're talking about smooth manifolds, then $M\times N$ is _not_ a manifold with boundary if $\partial M$ and $\partial N$ are both nonempty.